# Sort hash by array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash and an array with same length like the following:

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}
a = [2, 0, 1, 0]
```

I want to order the hash in increasing order of the values in the array. So the output would be something like:

```
h = {:b => 2, :d => 4, :c=> 3, :a => 1}
```

Ideally I want to introduce some randomness for ties. For the previous example, I want either the previous output or:

```
h = {:d => 4, :b => 2, :c=> 3, :a => 1}
```

---

This is what I tried.

```
b = a.zip(h).sort.map(&:last)
p Hash[b]
# => {:b=>2, :d=>4, :c=>3, :a=>1}
```

But I am not sure how to introduce the randomness.

Comment: I am not getting your array's role to sort the hash... Explain more about _..increasing order of the values in the array_.

Comment: Each (key, value) corresponds to an value of the array. For example `:a => 1` corresponds to `2` as `:b => 2` corresponds to `0`. In the output hash the "zeros" should come first, the "ones" second etc.

Comment: When addressing a question that seeks clarification (e.g., @Arup's), it is generally better to edit your question (e.g., "Edit: ...), than to respond with comments, as some readers may not read all he comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h.to_a.sort_by.each_with_index{|el,i| [a[i], rand]}.to_h
```

Comment: I don't believe you need `to_a`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right. I stumbled upon it. Since I'm not in the habit of sorting hashes,  I was mildly surprised `sort_by` returned an array. Considered an explicit `to_a` better, to explain the `to_h`,but not sure about it. Not very important though.

Comment: A detail: Since `Hash#each` returns a two-element array,  `Enumerable#sort_by` (and other Enumerable methods) acts on a hash the same way it acts on an array of two-element arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify what you have slightly:

```
def doit(h,a)
   Hash[a.zip(h).sort_by { |e,_| [e,rand] }.map(&:last)]
end

doit(h,a) #=> { b=>2, d=>4, c=>3, a=>1 }
doit(h,a) #=> { d=>4, b=>2, c=>3, a=>1 }
doit(h,a) #=> { b=>2, d=>4, c=>3, a=>1 }
doit(h,a) #=> { b=>2, d=>4, c=>3, a=>1 }
```